# How can I fix the "list index out of range" error?

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm working on a Battleship game and at this point I've created a Grid for the game and the "get_location" function is called by a for loop to randomly generate locations for each ship. There's "if" statements that test if the vessel will fit on the location selected before placing it, and then there's an add vessel function that places the ship on the grid.
But sometimes the AI places the ship and it goes off the grid and I get the "list index out of range" error.

I know what the error is saying, but I can't figure out how I can fix it. I hope someone can help out on how I could possibly fix this problem. Here's the part of my code that's causing the problem:

def get_location(index) :

```
# Get the name and size from the lists using the index.
name = VESSEL_NAMES[index]
size = VESSEL_SIZES[index]

column = random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH)
row = random.randint(0, GRID_HEIGHT)
direction = random.randint(H, V) # H=0, V=1 (global constants)
print()
if (direction == H and column + size > GRID_WIDTH) :
    get_location(index)
    print()
if (direction == V and row + size > GRID_HEIGHT) :
    get_location(index)
    print()
else :
    add_vessel(index, row, column, direction)
```

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: Looks like you want `randrange` instead of `randint` for your column and row. You probably do want `randint` for `direction`, but for consistency you could just do `randrange(0,2)` for that. Take a look at the `help(random.randrange)` output.

Comment: I tried changing it to randrange but still getting the error.

Comment: also, you mentioned "help(random.randrange) is that something that I can access for help? if so how do I access it.

Comment: Yes, open a python shell and type `import random;help(random.randrange)`

Comment: ok thanks, from what I understand about "randrange" it says it excludes the endpoint of the range. Yet even if the endpoint is excluded from being picked the ships are more than 2 spaces long and some part of the ship will go off the grid. :( which is causing the error.

Comment: any idea if there's another way for me to call the "else: add vessel" function so every location picked by the AI will be checked through the "IF" statements before they are passed to the "add_vessel" function.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe missing something here, but wouldn't random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH) potentially gives you GRID_WIDTH, which i assume would be out of index?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but "random.randint(0, GRID_WIDTH)" just selects a random integer between 0 and 9(which is the Grid Width) and assigns it to the variable. (column or row) and the "if" statements are supposed to validate it the vessels selected column+their size will go off the grid or not, and should call the function again to pick another location if found invalid.

Comment: apparently "else :
    add_vessel(index, row, column, direction)" function appears to be causing a problem with the "if" statements for to validate if the vessel will fit on the grid or not. (I think)